# Shared Post Doesn't Post Images to the Shared Object In the backend

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having a hard time sharing post with my function, My challenge is whenever i share a post the share images in the original post doesn't post the images to the new post image field, but rather it repost the images in the original share post field and so it makes it not possible to show the shared image! my question why am I getting this effect of post being reposted in the original image field and not the new shared post field! hoping for a solution ?

```
Here is my function for sharing post:

def share_post(request, pk):
    original_post = Post.objects.prefetch_related('groupimage_set').get(pk=pk)
   
    form = ShareForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_post = Post(
            shared_body = request.POST.get('description'),
            description = original_post.description,
            username = original_post.username,
            date_posted = original_post.date_posted,
            group       = original_post.group,
            video      = original_post.video,
            shared_on = datetime.now(),
            shared_user = request.user)
        new_post.save()
        form = GroupImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            for image in original_post.groupimage_set.all():
                new_post = GroupImage(post=original_post, 
                                      group=original_post.group,
                                      shared_user=request.user,
                                      image=image.image)
                
                new_post.save()
            return redirect('group:main',original_post.group.pk)
        else:
            form = GroupImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    ctx = {'form':form, 'original_post':original_post}
    return render(request,'group/share_form.html', ctx)
```

Here is my model for images and post

```
class Post(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(GroupEx, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="group_post")
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,related_name="group_user")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to="group_videos", blank=True)
    shared_body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    shared_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    shared_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')
```

Group image model

```
class GroupImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(GroupEx,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    shared_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='GroupImageLibrary/', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: why do you need `GroupImageForm` for sharing a post ? you just need the a description for the shared post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error was that you are passing `original_post` to the `GroupImage model` instead of `new_post`.
Try to change this part

```
    if form.is_valid():
        new_post = Post(
            shared_body = request.POST.get('description'),
            description = original_post.description,
            username = original_post.username,
            date_posted = original_post.date_posted,
            group       = original_post.group,
            video      = original_post.video,
            shared_on = datetime.now(),
            shared_user = request.user)
        new_post.save()
        form = GroupImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            for image in original_post.groupimage_set.all():
                new_post = GroupImage(post=original_post, 
                                      group=original_post.group,
                                      shared_user=request.user,
                                      image=image.image)
                
                new_post.save()
```

to

```
    if form.is_valid():
        new_post1 = Post(
            shared_body = request.POST.get('description'),
            description = original_post.description,
            username = original_post.username,
            date_posted = original_post.date_posted,
            group       = original_post.group,
            video      = original_post.video,
            shared_on = datetime.now(),
            shared_user = request.user)
        new_post1.save()
        for image in original_post.groupimage_set.all():
            new_post = GroupImage(post=new_post1, 
                                      group=original_post.group,
                                      shared_user=request.user,
                                      image=image.image)
                
            new_post.save()
            print("new_post",new_post) # just for debugging the program...
```

I think the other way you can handle a share post is to have a foreignkey on the post itself.let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: Your solution worked but am still not able to post multiple pictures to the shared object, it only shared one image if there are multiple images in original_post ? How do i resolve that @Thierno Amadou Sow

Comment: @Godda are you sure  that you don't have an indentation problem in your code ? because this code should work. i have updated it try it and let me know if you want to me to do a second method of handling the same problem because this method is not optimal.

Comment: Yes i just copied your update and used it, still having the same challenge it only uploads one  pictures out the six  and the print doesn't show any uploaded object afterward ! thank you so much for your help! but unfortunately  it didn't solve the it. I'm trying debugging it and hopefully will let you know if am able to get it upload all images!

Comment: @Godda could you please tell me what you got in the print for the debugging part ?

Comment: it printed new_post GroupImage object (803) @Thierno Amadou Sow

Comment: @Godda you said that you have six and why then the print only show one object ?

Comment: Yes i have six images  in the backend of the original_post with what i initially did it posted all the images to the original_post and not to the shared post! but with your solution it only post one picture out of the six ! which i don't know why !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243742/discussion-between-godda-and-thierno-amadou-sow).